# 日本語に違和感：タグのトップユーザー画面

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

タグの後に「件の質問」となっていますが、件数の値は下の欄です。
英語サイトでは「Questions」でした。

「件の」を削って「質問」にするか、「件」だけ削って「の質問」にするのが良さそうですね。

■赤く下線を引いたところ
[image: トップユーザー画面]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[日本語版](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers)と[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers)のタグのトップユーザー画面によると、[こちら](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/4807)のストリングだと思われます。ご提案いただきました通り「件の」を削って「質問」と変更いたしました。反映まで少しお待ちくださいませ。